# Async/Await works in Windows Form application, but it shouldn't

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, asynchronous

Based on [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) following code shouldn't work in Windows Forms application and I'm pretty much certain, that it didn't work in past, but recently I've discovered, that in .NET framework 4.7.02558 it works.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("One");

        var d = DelayAsync();

        Console.WriteLine("Three");

        d.Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("Five");
    }

    private async Task DelayAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Two");

        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Four");
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Test();
    }
}
```

Did I miss some a release log, or is something wrong (I mean right from user's perspective)?

Edit: An application should freeze after returning from awaited code because in Windows Forms is used CurrentContextSheduller.

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 Professional, `Console.WriteLine()` outputs to ˙Output˙ window in Visual Studio.

Comment: well, it dead-locks for me (as expected) in .net4.6.2 in debug and non-debug mode (output of `Console.WriteLine()` is only visible in debug mode). I currently don't have 4.7, so can't reproduce it.

Comment: VisualStudio 2017 Comunity with .net 4.7 freeze.

Comment: @SebastianBusek the application would freeze because there's only one UI thread, not because of `CurrentContextSheduller`. The current synchronization context is what *every* `await` will return/recreate and has different meaning for different types of applications. For Winforms/WPF, that's the single UI thread. Anyway, no repro on 4.7.1. The app freezes.

Comment: @SebastianBusek how did you determine that the app didn't freeze? Were you able to click on the button twice?

Comment: @SebastianBusek are you actually seeing `Four`, and `Five` in your output?

Comment: Yeah, I'm able to click at the button more than once and also an application should stop responding, but after a second I'm able to move the window (I shouldn't be able to) and in the Output window there is: One
Two
'WindowsFormsApp1.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WindowsFormsApp1.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\mscorlib.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_cs_b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.resources.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
Three
Four
Five

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered. The problem was caused by ReSharper Build & Run. For some reason, the build wasn't done and switching from ReSharper Build to Visual Studio build program behaves "correctly".
Latest build was done with `.ConfigureAway(false)`, so that's a root cause of why it worked and shouldn't.

Comment: If you change `var d = DelayAsync();` in `var d = Task.Run(async () => await DelayAsync());` you'll have it working again :)

Answer (score 1):

Testing on 4.7.1 I get the following results:

> One
>   Two
>   Three

`Four`, and `Five` never get displayed.  It seems to be "not-working as intended" for me, as execution of `await Task.Delay(1000);` is blocking.